# Expression Trees in C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, code-generation, expression-trees

For the very first time I am exploring expression trees. I have a few basic doubts.

So essentially , an expression takes only a lambda expression . Ans then we can Compile() the lambda expression to MSIL code which in turn returns a generic delegate. We can invoke the returned delegate as it is . Is my understanding correct ?

If it is here is what I am trying to achieve: `((10*5)+(9/4))`

```
BinaryExpression b1 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Multiply, Expression.Constant(10), Expression.Constant(5));//(10*5)
BinaryExpression b2 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Divide, Expression.Constant(9), Expression.Constant(4));//(9/4)
BinaryExpression b4 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, b1, b2);//((10*5)+(9/4))
```

So at this point we have made the `lambda expression body` . Now to turn it to a `full lambda expression` we need to call

```
Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(b4).Compile());
```

**I am not getting this part . And this does not work also .**

Why this `Func<int,int>`?

Is it like the inner expressions will take only int as param and the entire expression will return an int?

Obviously this does not work. How the generated lambda looks like ?

I am getting the entire picture? How to make this work?

Comment: *And this does not work also .*, what does it do? Does it give you an error? What error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(b4).Compile()
> ```

`Func<int,int>` is a signature for lambdas that take a single `int` parameter, and return an `int`. Your lambda has a different signature.

> Obviously this does not work.

Your lambda does not take any parameters, so you need `Func<int>` instead.

> How the generated lambda looks like?

Generated lambda is a callable object. If you would like to evaluate the expression that you get back, cast and call it, like this:

```
var compiledLambda = (Func<int>)Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(b4).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(compiledLambda());
//                              ^^
```

The above prints `52`, as expected.

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/06NPuw)

If you would like to make a `Func<int,int>`, add a parameter to your expression, e.g. make it `(p*5)+(9/4)` where `p` is an `int` parameter:

```
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
BinaryExpression b1 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Multiply, p, Expression.Constant(5));//(p*5)
BinaryExpression b2 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Divide, Expression.Constant(9), Expression.Constant(4));//(9/4)
BinaryExpression b4 = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, b1, b2);
var compiledLambda = (Func<int,int>)Expression.Lambda<Func<int,int>>(b4, new[] {p}).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(compiledLambda(10)); // Prints 52
Console.WriteLine(compiledLambda(8));  // Prints 42
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/G6ZUKC)

Answer (score 4):

You can create your lambda expression like that:

```
LambdaExpression lb = Expression.Lambda(b4);
```

You can then compile this expression to a delegate:

```
Delegate dlg = lb.Compile();
```

And cast this delegate to a `Func<int>`:

```
Func<int> f = (Func<int>)dlg;
```

And you can use this as usual:

```
Console.WriteLine(f()); // 52
```

---

The generic way works, too. Why *do* you use `Func<int,int>`? Your expression takes no input and returns a single `int`:

```
Func<int> f = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(b4);
```

The generic argument leads to a `LambdaExpression` with a `Compile` method that returns a `Func<int>` instead of a `Delegate` that you'd need to cast again.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
Console.WriteLine(Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(b4).Compile());
```

you actually print it with [`Console.WriteLine(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which prints the name of the `Type` of the argument.

since the line:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(b4).Compile();
```

only compiles the lambda and ***provides you the `delegate` - not its invocation's result***.

You need to ***invoke the compiled lambda*** and print only the result:

```
Func<int> result = (Func<int>)Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(b4).Compile();
Console.WriteLine(result());
```

---

*Also note that you try to compile the `delegate` as a `Func<int,int>` which takes an `int` argument and provides an `int` result but your code doesn't require an argument so you need to use `Func<int>`.*